# Does getElementsByClassName keep ordering?

Tags: javascript

The webpage I am working with contains an alphabetically sorted list of div's that all have the same class. If I call `document.getElementsByClassName('classname')`, can I be sure that the array it returns will be sorted in HTML order?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

> The collection then represents a view of the subtree rooted at the collection’s root, containing only nodes that match the given filter. The view is linear. In the absence of specific requirements to the contrary, **the nodes within the collection must be sorted in tree order**.

— https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#old-style-collections

Answer (score 3):

I found following statement in "The WHATWG Blog":

> The getElementsByClassName(classNames) method takes a string that
>   contains an unordered set of unique space-separated tokens
>   representing classes. When called, the method must return a live
>   NodeList object containing all the elements in the document, in tree
>   order, that have all the classes specified in that argument, having
>   obtained the classes by splitting a string on spaces. If there are no
>   tokens specified in the argument, then the method must return an empty
>   NodeList. If the document is in quirks mode, then the comparisons for
>   the classes must be done in an ASCII case-insensitive manner,
>   otherwise, the comparisons must be done in a case-sensitive manner.

https://blog.whatwg.org/tag/getelementsbyclassname